# JMeter - contribute new function(s) to JMeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I want to add more functions to JMeter, for example encryption `__sha512` which will encrypt string using SHA 512.

What's the process of [contribute](http://jmeter.apache.org/building.html) new function(s) to JMeter? can I add it as an enhancement to JMeter and create a patch or should it be added as a plugin manager?

In plugin manager there's already [Function](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/) project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JMeter plugins project is a 3rd party project with no relation to JMeter.
Users will have to install plugin manager and install then function plugin.

If you contribute to Core JMeter it will be available OOTB.

So if you want to contribute to JMeter:

- open an enhancement request
- attach you patch or point to your PR in github

See:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/building.html

JMeter functions are located here:

- https://github.com/apache/jmeter/tree/trunk/src/functions/org/apache/jmeter/functions

JUnit Tests should be provided as well:

- https://github.com/apache/jmeter/tree/trunk/test/src/org/apache/jmeter/functions

Comment: To add JUnit test is enough? should it be tested in GUI ? can GUI be tested in nightly build?

Comment: for functions JUnit is enough. You can add integration tests , have a look at TCP_TESTs.jmx and in build.xml for tests that run JMeter. What do you mean by can gui be tested in nightly build ?

Comment: After change is accepted/added, can/should I download nightly build and check JMeter application is working with the new function(s) ?

Comment: Yes, it can be available few minutes after merge of your PR if no issue occurs or at least in nightly build. You can also provide additional fixes after it is merged